# Rotate two points on f-curve by opposite amounts

Tags: fcurves

If I have two points on a curve and I want to rotate the handles the same amount I can select both handles, choose pivot from individual centers and rotate them. However what if I want to rotate them in opposite directions?

One way to do this is to rotate one point by pressing R and specifying an angle, and rotate the other point with the inverse of that angle. Are there other ways to do this if you don't know what angle you want to rotate beforehand?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done in 2 ways:

Selecting the first side inner handle and rotating it, then selecting the other side inner handle and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the last rotation. Before doing anything else, press <kbd>F9</kbd>(<kbd>F6</kbd> in blender 2.79) to open the options window. In that window you get the currently used angle, which if negativ needs to be made positive to mirror the rotation. Else other way around.

See in the little visual explanation:

[image: rotation mirrored by using F9 and changing the value]

The other way is by indirectly rotating through moving the handles:

You select the one side inner handle and press <kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and move the handle to obtain the angle you want. After that you select the other sides inner handle and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the movement, resulting in the exact same angle just mirrored. While rotation can also be repeated, it would be in the same direction and not result in a mirrored effect.

Little visual explanation:

[image: rotating handles mirrored effect]

Comment: Thanks! Repeat the last action command is pretty neat! This could be a viable approach.

Comment: Updated after i remembered that repeating the last action allows changing of parameters with F9 in some cases. Rotation being one ;)

Comment: Changing parameters is a feature in Blender 2.8 and later right? Unfortunately I'm using 2.79. Still good to know, thanks!

Comment: Just downloaded 2.79 and tried, it's possible there too, adjusted the answer.

Comment: Incredible, thank you very much! This is a really powerful tool. Could be very handy for modeling and for mirroring bone transforms in pose mode as well!